# Angular Formly options value causes Placeholder bug

Tags: angular, angular-formly

My options dropdown has a boolean value in this Formly field. Whenever the value is false, this causes the placeholder and the options label to be overlayed over each other.

I don't have this issues with any of my other formly items, just ones with the value of false. Is there a solution for this?

Edit: I may be having trouble uploading photos, but I found another example of this error here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-formly-demo
The only difference is I'm not using Material

[image: formly-true-option]
[image: formly-false-option]

```
{
                className: 'dropdown',
                key: 'emergencyActionPlan',
                id: 'emergencyActionPlan',
                type: 'dropdown',
                templateOptions: {
                  placeholder: 'Emergency Action Plan',
                  required: true,
                  options: [
                    { value: true, label: 'Yes' },
                    { value: false, label: 'No' }
                  ],
                  labelProp: 'label',
                  valueProp: 'value'
                }
}
```

Comment: That stackblitz you've referenced replaces the formly control with their own custom input, I'm not sure you can use it as a comparison. Can you set up a stackblitz of your own with it? When I remove their custom control it works just fine. See: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-formly-demo-hlxbfy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts all I did was remove `types: [ {name: 'input', component: FormlyFieldInput} ],` from the module.

Comment: It was just meant to be a visible example of the bug, not a programmatic representation. I've also found that if an options value is set to 0 (zero) the same issue happens. But not if it's set to undefined.

Comment: Team may have figured it out. It's still being worked on but apparently the textarea element has a class set to a ternary operator that checks if the value is not. ```
    class="{{ !formControl.value ? 'p-filled' : '' }}"``` which would cause falsies and 0 to return null class

Comment: What I was trying to get at is it's not the framework, it's something custom. If you can paste the code that would help. For your specific use case you can try `class="{{ !formControl.value && formContro.value !== false ? 'p-filled' : '' }}"`